# How to test application controller before filter methods in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, functional-testing, before-filter

I have a `before_filter` on my `ApplicationController` class and I want to write a test for it? Where should I write this test into? I do not want to go into every subclass controller test file and repeat the test about this filter.

Hence, what is the recommended way to test `ApplicationController` before_filters?

Note that I am using `Rails 3.2.1` with `minitest`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My case is slightly different than yours, but I needed to do something similar to test authentication across the site (with Devise). Here's how I did it:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

# application_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class TestableController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render :text => 'rendered content here', :status => 200
  end
end

class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests TestableController

  context "anonymous user" do
    setup do
      get :show
    end
    should redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
  end
end
```

If there's specific controllers that need to skip the before filter I'll have a test to make sure they skip it in the specific controller's tests. This isn't quite your situation as I'm interested in the effect of the method, not just knowing it was invoked, but I thought I'd share in case you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on @bmaddy answser, you do need to setup routing for the specs to run.

Here is a rails 5 working example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class BaseController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render nothing: true
  end
end

class BaseControllerTest  < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'redirects if user is not logedin' do
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'base' => 'base#index'
    end

    get '/base'

    assert_equal 302, status
    assert_redirected_to 'http://somewhere.com'
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end

  test 'returns success if user is loggedin' do
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'base' => 'base#index'
    end

    mock_auth!

    get '/base'
    assert_equal 200, status
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I now believe that I have to have all my controllers tests test about the before_filter existence and that this filter works as expected. This is because, I cannot know whether a controller uses a `skip_before_filter` when it shouldn't.

Hence, I decided to use `mock` (`@controller.expects(:before_filter_method)`) to make sure that the filter is called. So, for example, in a `index` action I write in my test:

```
test "get index calls the before filter method" do
  @controller.expects(:before_filter_method)
  # fire
  get :index      
end
```

This will make sure that my controller calls `before_filter_method` on the particular action. I have to do this on all my actions tests.

If anyone else has a better solution, let me know.

Comment: Why don't you simply test for what would happen with or without that filter? This way you are decoupled from the filter and only care *what* happens if the filter is called, not whether it was called or not. The added benefit of this is that you could rename the filter, change it's scope, move it to some other class, or outright replace it with an observer, a service, or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I want something like this I just test the expected behaviour without taking into account that this particular behaviour may be implemented in a filter and not in a method per se. So for the following simple scenario :

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_resource, :only => [:show, :edit]

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def index
  end

  #########
  protected 
  #########

  def load_resource
    @resource = Model.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I would simple test that #show and #edit assign the @resource thing. This works for simple scenarios pretty much ok. If the filter is applied to a lot of actions/controllers then you can extract the testing code and reuse it amongst the tests.

Comment: If the filter is on a specific controller, I agree with your approach. My filter is declared on `ApplicationController` class (and inherited to all controllers deriving from it). The filter method that I use has to do with checks on the request. I need to write a test in a place where I can use methods like the ones (or equivalent?) I use when testing a concrete controller. Maybe your answer to my problem is in your last phrase ("If the filter ...amongst the tests"), but I cannot see that. Also, how do I test that the method attached to `before_filter` is really attached to it?

Comment: You can write a test suite that gets included in every controller test and runs for every action. This should be simple(r) to do using RSpec using the 'it_behaves_like' (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group) thing, but on simple Test::Unit you can do such stuff. Maybe you can take inspiration from ActiveModel::Lint:Tests (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Lint/Tests.html - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/lint.rb)